# Usage of the word "importune."

Tags: meaning

Take a look at [this article](https://www.foreignpolicyjournal.com/2010/08/02/the-red-face-of-israel/),

> Several decades ago Israel began presenting itself as the “bulwark against communism” in the Middle East and as of vital strategic **importune** to the USA vis-à-vis the USSR in the region.

- Is the word *importune* used here as a verb or noun?
- If it is used as a noun, what is its meaning?

Comment: It looks like a typo...probably they meant "importance".

Comment: I agree it's a typo, they meant "importance", it's very importunate really.

Comment: I think that it's possible that an OCR misreading is involved. Compare 'unperformed on the part of siu-h person the performance of which affects or is of importune? to petitioner' found in [a Google search for "of importune to"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&ei=0SayWqTzBob0gAa14LnQDQ&q=%22of+importune+to%22&oq=%22of+importune+to%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i30k1.11529.12463.0.12978.3.3.0.0.0.0.70.182.3.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.111...0i8i7i30k1j0i8i7i10i30k1.0.8UFrjxmJFsg) to with ...

Comment: 'is of importance to' in the actual article at [Wisconsin Session Laws](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rOogAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA1330&lpg=PA1330&dq=%22of+importune+to%22&source=bl&ots=X8g31jxaU5&sig=nUvgpszouJQkbfFnUmkzIi_pJgI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-0vGMjv3ZAhUEDcAKHRyNDNQQ6AEIQTAG#v=onepage&q=%22of%20importune%20to%22&f=false).